# How to use PhpStorm Foundation template?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, compass-sass, zurb-foundation, phpstorm

I would like to get some skills with Foundation and what was not my surprise when I saw that PhpStorm (which is my main web projects IDE) purposed a Foundation template.

After downloading the template and reading the beginning of Foundation doc, I realized that the version provided by PhpStorm was quite different from the original.

[image]

I almost have no ruby skills but I already installed Ruby, rails, compass gem and sass gem. 
My question is how to use this template, and how to compile it cleanly?

Comment: do you mean...you want an explanation about the above folder structure...sub folders and all that

Comment: sounds like a question for phpstorm support, is there anything specific in the readme? This looks like the Sass version which would require compass or codekit unless phpstorm handles the preprocessing internally.

Comment: Why just not download the original template from Foundation?

Comment: @MESSIAH hum I already understand what /docs/ , /js/ , /lib/ , /scss/ stand for but what about templates ? Have I to build my project here ? how to compile the sources ? Why do they put a Gruntfile. I'm just a little bit confuse for example to have 2 scss/ directories...

Comment: @JamesJamesJames As far as I searched PhpStorm support sass compilation but only file by file. Not very useful. The readme contains a lot of greetings, licence and content of the repository... but without any details..

Comment: @JustinD. If nobody can explain me this template, it's what I will do but I think if PhpStorm downloaded their own repository, it should exist a reason..
And sorry for my dirty english... it's not my motherlanguage.

Comment: @cocoggu I don't see an advantage to using this template. Just `gem install zurb-foundation` then `compass create myproject -r zurb-foundation --using foundation` cd to that directory and run `compass watch`

Comment: Thank you @JamesJamesJames can you give me a "real" answer, so I can accept your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit/Comment on original question:

I don't see an advantage to using this template.

Just run it like you normally would with a Sass/Scss workflow:

```
gem install zurb-foundation
compass create myproject -r zurb-foundation --using foundation
cd mymyproject
compass watch
```

Now every time you save a file compass will compile your Scss files into the `stylesheets` directory.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that there is two scss folders because one is for your project libraries : foundation, for instance. This folder contains code you have downloaded. Now, the scss folder inside the template folder must be custom css code to manipulate the default look of foundation.

To use the template, you'll need to reference every file in your index page/all HTML pages.

From [sass' website](http://sass-lang.com/tutorial.html) :

> To translate this Sass file into a CSS file, run
>
> ```
> sass --watch style.scss:style.css
> ```

Comment: Thanks you but I think the compilation can be more easy than that.
The method you purpose is file by file and when I say "cleanly" it's what I what I mean. 
Compile all the files (even ruby or I don't know which files I have to compile) should be as easy as typing "grunt" for NodeJS. Or if there are no similar command with Foundation, said me. Anyway thanks you for your explanations of directories. It's what I was thinking about but I was not sure...

Answer (score 0):

You should use the console and execute the following settings:
inside the docs/ directory run `bundle install`.

To get the docs to compile during development you'll want to run `bundle exec foreman start`. 
At that point you can access the docs by going to `http://localhost:4000`

Answer (score 0):

Don't use Template or Foundation Project in PhpStorm, create your own :

You need Git, Ruby 1.9+ and NodeJs

- First, install bower :
  npm install -g bower grunt-cli
- next install Foundation :
  gem install foundation
- Let's go to your projetc directory :
  cd /your_site
- Create new Foundation Project! :
  foundation new project_name --libsass

That's All.

If you need to update Foundation :
Go to your Foundation Directory and :
foundation update